# Use Jenkins Parametrised Build to control execution of Post-Build Actions

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, post-build

Is there any way that I can use Jenkins Choice Parameters to control the execution of Post-Build jobs in a project?

I have my project which is building a war file and sometimes (not all the times) I would like this war file to be send to Amazon S3 bucket so I can deploy it to an EC2 Tomcat Container. I don't want Jenkins to keep sending the war file to S3 every time it builds the project (which happens many times a day) and I want a method to control when to send the war file to S3.

The only option I can see is to duplicate my current Jenkins project and have the new project send war file to S3 but this means that I will end up having multiple Jenkins projects doing 'almost' exactly the same thing which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nah, don't make a new build plan for that. even declarative pipelines support this use case like no man's business. once you have a parameter (from the parameters step. these will allow you to "Build with parameters" and have an actual person check a checkbox when you want a war shipped off), you can simply reference it via params.MY_PARAM_NAME. just replace the `echo`s below with actual code:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }

  parameters { booleanParam(name: 'SEND_WAR_TO_S3', defaultValue: false, description: 'Send resulting war file to s3?') }

  stages {
    stage('hot_stage') {
      steps {
        echo 'generating war...'
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    always {
      script {
        if (params.SEND_WAR_TO_S3) {
          echo 'sending war to s3'
        } else {
          echo 'not sending war to s3'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @KevinBurnett I will try the pipeline option and will let you know what goes. Cheers.